# Cant create a markdown document in R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, markdown

Im new to R, and when I attempt to create an R markdown document in Rstudio theres a pop up saying that "Creating R markdown documents requires an updated version of of the digest package". It also asks if I wish to install this package now. I click yes, and after installing the package and trying to create a markdown document once again, the exact same pop up appears.

What can I do to fix this? Do I need to unload the packages somehow before I can use them?

Comment: I recommend you to reinstall both R and Rstudio and to try again

Comment: Not to give silly advice, but quit RStudio and open it again, then see what happens

Comment: Neither of these worked for me sadly.

Comment: @Pame have you tried to reinstall the ``rmarkdown`` package itself?

Comment: I managed to solve it finally. I had to manually go in and install the digest package myself. Clicking yes on the popup asking if I wanted to install it did not do the job apparently.

Comment: Personally, I have never seen an install pop-up on rstudio. Always install whatever package(s) you require using `install.packages("package_name")`.

Comment: @Pame By the way, What operating system are you on? I often find that R requires some library that Ubuntu does not have. So, I have to install that library outside R. Happens ALOT.